# Applying Striped Colors (Pattern) on pie chart extjs

Tags: css, extjs, colors

How to apply striped combination of pattern color in pie chart in ExtJs.

Comment: Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
new Ext.Panel({
width: 400,
height: 400,
title: 'Pie Chart with Legend - Favorite Season',
renderTo: 'container',
items: {
    store: store,
    xtype: 'piechart',
    dataField: 'total',
    categoryField: 'season',
    series: [{
        style: {
            colors: ["#ff2400", "#94660e", "#00b8bf", "#edff9f"]
        }
    }],
    extraStyle:
    {
        legend:
        {
            display: 'bottom',
            padding: 5,
            font:
            {
                family: 'Tahoma',
                size: 13
            }
        }
    }
}
});
```

Reference : http://jlorenzen.blogspot.in/2010/10/how-to-change-extjs-piechart-colors.html.
You can add more details, what do you want? Is it your requirement?

Comment: I need to apply the following color pattern to pie chart:              background: repeating-linear-gradient((135deg,
  #000, #000 .25em /* black stripe */,
  #0092b7 0, #0092b7 .75em /* blue stripe */);